# Function does not return expected dataframe output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

I'm a newbie in programming, python, nlp and stackoverflow so grateful for your patience!

I have developed a function that extracts some text from several pdf files and sets up a pandas dataframe with it as well as other details from the original pdf files.

Outside of the function set up, these steps work well but once I 'package' them in the function I can't get the output to work and the resulting dataframe stays empty. I'm clearly missing something, help please! :)

Here's the function (accessing text from relevant numbered file -Identified by Trustcode and Year).

```
def Accessingtxt_func(Trustcode):
    DFTrust_Text1=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Text','Month','Year','Type', 'Trustcode'])
    for year in range(2021,2023):
        with open(os.path.join(mypath,f'{ts}Trust{Trustcode}-{year}a.txt'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fw:
            txt_content = extract_text(f'Trust{Trustcode}-{year}a.pdf') 
            fw.write(txt_content)   
            txt_content= txt_content.split('\n\n')
             DFTrust_Text1=DFTrust_Text1.append({'Text': txt_content, 'Year': {year}, 'Month':9, 'Type':1, 'Trustcode':Trustcode},ignore_index=True)
        return DFTrust_Text1
    year=year+1
    return DFTrust_Text1
```

The function compiles fine, and I then run it in a loop like this

```
for Trustcode in range(12,14):
    print(Trustcode)
    Accessingtxt_func(Trustcode)
    DFTrust_Text1.head()
```

Which also runs fine, however I can't get it to provide the dataframe head and when calling the function in each loop step. Don't know why either.

I then still call the dataframe out after the loop like so

```
DFTrust_Text1.head()
```

But I get an empty dataframe shell, not the expected dataframe with rows for Trustcodes 12,13 and years 2021 and 2022.

```
Text    Month   Year    Type    Trustcode
```

I've tried with various positionings of the dataframe inside outside, global/local variable, but can't get it to work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to asign a dataframe when calling the function:

```
newdf = Accessingtxt_func(Trustcode)
newdf.head()
```

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. The amended calling loop was set as this: DFTrust_Text=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Text','Month','Year','Type', 'Trustcode'])
for Trustcode in range(12,14):
    print(Trustcode)
    newDF=Accessingtxt_func(Trustcode)
    DFTrust_Text=pd.concat([DFTrust_Text,newDF])